# Send report by email - Oracle BI Publisher

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I have created a report with BI Publisher, and I try to schedule it in order to run daily and send an email.
I configured the mail server attributes, such as the mail server, port , username and password. 
I tested it and it said "connection established successfully"
then I schedule the job, and when it is time to run the job, nothing happens.There is nothing in job history and no emails are sent. 
Do you know maybe what is causing this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there anything in the BI Publisher logs?
<OBI_HOME>/user_projects/domains/<your_domain>/servers/<your_bi_server>/logs/bipublisher/bipublisher.log
Also check that it's actually scheduled in the future, sometimes there is a timezone set to GMT-11 or something that might make it happen in the past. What if you scheduler it with Frequency set to Once and select the Run Now option?
Are you sure your SMTP server is allowed to send email to the recipient email?

Comment: The only this that comes out in the BI Publisher logs is this :

Comment: pOwnerOp Equals
jobinfo : start   getSchedulingService :Wed Jan 18 14:15:55 EET 2017
 start time 1: Wed Jan 18 14:15:55 EET 2017
 start time 2: Wed Jan 18 14:15:55 EET 2017
 start time 3: Wed Jan 18 14:15:55 EET 2017
 start time 4: Wed Jan 18 14:15:55 EET 2017
 start time 5: Wed Jan 18 14:15:55 EET 2017
 start time 6: Wed Jan 18 14:15:55 EET 2017

Comment: Also, when I go to report history there is nothing, only a Warning that says:

Comment: User has no global access report output privilages; some data may be excluded

Comment: Please edit your question with the log entries you've found.

Comment: This is either a permissions/Role-based access control (RBAC) issue. The issue could also lie in the data (row-level) security.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no comments like '--' in either the trigger or bursting SQL. These codes seem to be interpreting the SQL in a single line without breaks. This will render the SQL useless as most of the SQL then is a comment.